# Best way to schedule infinite toast notifications in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10, scheduling, toast

I am creating an app that reminds you every `x` minutes to get up and walk around. I have created the following toast notification, which executes at the interval of the frequency combo box that the user can set.

```
// Create the toast notification
ToastNotificationManagerCompat.History.Clear();

new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddText("Time to get up!")
    .SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long)
    .Schedule(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(GetDurationFromIndex(frequency.SelectedIndex)));
```

(The first line clears old notifications, since we don't want them to have to clear each instance every time a new reminder is made)

My code properly schedules and displays toast notifications, and the `GetDurationFromIndex()` method just returns the minutes amount given the index of the combo box. This is great for one notification, but I want to repeatedly schedule these, one after another, to keep alerting the user to move every `x` minutes.

#### Method 1

Implement a loop that executes to schedule a notification at `x` minutes, `x + x` minutes, `x + x + x` minutes, ...

If the user changes the frequency, I delete every scheduled toast notification and reschedule.

#### Method 2

I create a background thread that runs and manually creates a new toast notification at each interval. Instead of scheduling, I simply use a timer/sleep interval to continually send notifications every `x` minutes.

When the user changes the frequency I simply adjust the timer/sleep duration for the next entry.

I think Method 2 makes more sense because it might not be respectful to the OS to schedule infinity toast notifications. However, this means I have to implement a background thread and keep the program from exiting when it's closed (minor issue). What do you guys suggest? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's a "toast notification"? (sorry, not good at c#)

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE A toast notification isn't C# dependent, it's just a notification that displays temporarily about important stuff on your OS. In Windows 10 it's notifications that slide across the bottom left of your desktop. On Android it's the little white bubble that displays at the bottom of your screen sometimes. etc.

Comment: So it's not always guaranteed that it'll work, because the user can go into Settings and turn it off?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Yes, users can disable notifications in Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Timer control (it is a standard control, look for it in the toolbox of Visual Studio).
Set the Interval property with the value you want (in milliseconds).
When the property Enabled is set to True it will start firing the Tick event at the interval specified.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0